# How can I use private fields in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

When I try to run the following code that uses a private field, I get an "Invalid character" error at the position of `#`.

```
class MyClass {
    #x =  10;
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
    …
}
```

I get this error:

`2:5 - error TS1127: Invalid character.`

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: There aren't that many characters in the code you posted. Which one looks the most invalid to you? Which one haven't you ever seen in any TypeScript example? Hint: the error message gives you the line and column of the invalid character.

Comment: @JBNizet Why it is impossible to use the symbol # if it is in javascript?

Comment: Because the JavaScript language designers decided so.

Comment: @JBNizet Any javascript code will always work in typescript.so say the developers of typescript.

Comment: But that's not valid JavaScript. Maybe it will be, at some time.

Comment: @SilicumSilium I think that only applies to stabilized features. For instance, Node 10 gives the same error, while it works fine in Node 12.9.0.

Comment: @grooveplex I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to use `private` keyword:

```js
class MyClass {
    private x =  10;
}
```

**Implement ES Private Fields** is on the TypeScript [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) in the Future section (so, I guess, earliest in version 3.7).

Comment: the future, what is better to use in typescript # or private ?

Comment: @SilicumSilium this is speculation, but I think `#` will take off, considering that's what un-typed JavaScript will most likely use.

Comment: @grooveplex I think so too.Thank you.

Comment: I think `private` will continue being predominantly used. It more readable and better fit other keywords `public` and `protected`. But it's good there will be a choice. Let's see what happens.